# Rename all files in directory and subdirectory

Tags: bash

How do I rename files in directory and subdirectory?
I found this program, but I need to go change files in subdirectory.

```
for file in *@me01
do
  mv "$file" "${file/@me01/_me01}"
done
```

```
n@me01
```

to

```
n_me01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following one-liner will likely work for you:

```
 find . -type f -name '*@me01' -execdir rename '@me01' '_me01' {} \;
```

The following form is likely more correct as it will change only the *last* `@` to `_` if there are multiple occurrences of @me01 in the file:

```
for f0 in $(find . -type f -name '*@me01')
do
    f1=$(printf '%s' "$f0" | sed 's/@me01$/_me01/')
    mv "$f0" "$f1"
done
```

This latter form is also more flexible and can be built upon more easily as the regex language in sed is much more powerful than rename expressions.

If rename of directories is also required the following can easily be added...

Either:

```
find . -type d -name '*@me01' -execdir rename '@me01' '_me01' {} \;
```

Or:

```
for d0 in $(find . -type d -name '*@me01')
do
    d1=$(printf '%s' "$d0" | sed 's/@me01$/_me01/')
    mv "$d0" "$d1"
done
```

Comment: it doesn't work, and I don't have files named FOO. thank you

Comment: it works now thank so much.
but I use only the first part :
for f0 in $(find . -type f -name '*@me01')
do
    f1=$(printf '%s' "$f0" | sed 's/@me01$/_me01/')
    mv "$f0" "$f1"
done.  
Can you explain to me please why the second for with $d0" "$d1".
THANK YOU AGAIN !!

Comment: Well, the way that **find** works is that it is going to spit out a list.  If we don't specify `-type` then it will spit out directories first.  If we rename the directories before the files while **find** is spitting out it's list, that would probably be bad because all our dependent file paths that are continuing to stream out afterwards would be invalid.  The idea above is to process directories (`-type d`) separate from files (`-type f`) so that there is no possibility of conflict.

Comment: Oh.... after re-reading your question, I recognized my mistake... I originally read "rename all files and directories" -- I will amend my response.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar

for name in **/*@me01; do
    mv "$name" "${name%@me01}_me01"
done
```

This enables the `globstar` shell option in `bash` which makes `**` match across path separators in pathnames.

It also uses a standard parameter substitution to delete the `@me01` portion at the very end of the found pathname and replace it with `_me01`.